# Sticky Post Doesn't always work

Tags: posts, blog, sticky-post

so i have a blog and i want to make a post a sticky post that stays at the top.
But for some reason, on the home page where i only display 4 posts, the sticky post doesn't work when the sticky post isn't in the newest 4 posts.
It all works perfectly in the "All Posts Page" though.
Anybody know how to fix this issue? thanks

Comment: I'd have a look at your theme's code to see if it's setting `'ignore_sticky_posts' => true` on the home page query for some reason, and debug that.

Comment: thanks for the reply, what specific files could i be looking at to see if ignore_sticky_posts is set to true?

Comment: Your theme's files probably. I don't know what theme you're using so I've no idea what files it will have, but try funcitons.php and the home page template if it's obvious which one that is, plus anything else that looks like included code.